# redirecting to a url from a templatefeild in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a grid view in my page in which i added a template feild.inserted a button which upon clicking will redirect the user to the actual request to make edits. The button that i added in the item template is bound to the data.The below is the code for the template feild

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequestId" SortExpression="roc_id">
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("roc_id") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" 
                         Text='<%# Bind("roc_id") %>' />
       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

how do i read the text from the botton click and redirect the user to the request that they click.I have listed the url below and i need to read the requestid at the end of url

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Edit.asp?ROCID=
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What text from button click are you talking about? You are only providing button2_click event, no sign on the rest of the code!

Comment: formatted the code.Sorry

Comment: need to read the text roc_id to the end of url

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GridView.RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) to capture the `button click` event.

Also, you need to add a command name to the button in template field.

There is a good article about [Respond to Button Events in a GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which will help you